# Selling images licensed under CC BY-SA 4.0 in game

Tags: licensing, creative-commons

I am making a game. It is free-to-play. Is it legal to take the top-hat from the Emoji One (v1) icon set licensed under CC BY-SA 4.0 and sell it as an in-game cosmetic items?

https://iconify.design/icon-sets/emojione-v1/top-hat.html

Answer (score 1):

I presume you want to sell (licenses to) software that *uses* the icons, not the icons themselves. As long as you don't modify them, and tell your users where to get them (and possibly change them for others) and state clearly under what conditions they are being used I believe you are in the clear.

Comment: I want to sell the hats as in-game items that can be worn by the player. The software itself is free to play.